# Passing parameter to stylesheet with saxon

Tags: parameters, xslt, saxon

- I am using `net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl` to do some transformation to multiple XML files.
- I am using the collection function to get the XML files.

What I want to do, and don't know if it is possible, is to pass a variable to the stylesheet which contain the path of the directory where my XML files are. I want to pass that variable from my Java code.

```
    <xsl:for-each 
        select="for $x in(collection('MYVAR?select=*.xml;recurse=yes'))
                    return saxon:discard-document($x)//testsuites">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use

```
<xsl:for-each select="for $x in(collection(concat($MYVAR, '?select=*.xml;recurse=yes')))return saxon:discard-document($x)//testsuites">
```

Note that MYVAR should be a file URL, not a (platform dependant) directory path.

[edit]
In your XSLT you need

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0">

  <xsl:param name="MYVAR"/>

  ...

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

in your Java code use the method http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/Transformer.html#setParameter%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29 e.g.

```
transformer.setParameter("MYVAR", "file:///C:/dir/subdir/dir");
```

Comment: I think you didn't get me. What I ask is how to put the URL in $MYVAR using Java code

Comment: this isn't working. I'm getting 
Error on line 9 of xslGetDataToXmlJUnit.xsl:
  FODC0004: The file or directory file:/Users/admin/Documents/$MYVAR does not exist

Comment: That error messages sounds as if you don't use `concat($MYVAR, '?select=*.xml;recurse=yes')`, as suggested, but rather something like `'$MYVAR?select=*.xml;recurse=yes'`. If you still have problems then post enough code allowing us to reproduce the problem easily.

Answer (score 0):

Use a parameter in your stylesheet:

```
<xsl:param name="MYVAR" />
```

Set the parameter in Java like this before invoking the transform:

```
transformer.setParameter("MYVAR", 'file:/some/folder');
```

Reference the parameter in the stylesheet as you would any variable or parameter:

```
<xsl:for-each select="for $x in
                        (collection(concat($MYVAR, '?select=*.xml;recurse=yes')))
                          return saxon:discard-document($x)//testsuites">
```

Comment: this isn't working. I'm getting Error on line 9 of xslGetDataToXmlJUnit.xsl: FODC0004: The file or directory file:/Users/admin/Documents/$MYVAR does not exist

Comment: It works for me.  Ensure that you are indeed setting the param correctly.  The value of `$MYVAR` should be 'file:/Users/admin/Documents` and should not contain "$MYVAR".

Comment: I'm sorry but i double check, the xsl:param doesn't see the transformer.setParameter
I dont know why.